How to auto-restart Azure web app post deployment through CICD (Bitbucket/ Git)?
I am trying to deploy Spring Boot app to Azure web-app/ app service.
Azure web app changes is not reflecting post deployment of new changes through CICD(bitbucket/ Git). It's reflecting once restarted manually post deployment. I want to automate it. I tried adding Restart-AzWebAppSlot in the deployment steps in .yaml file but didn't work.
Below is the sample .yaml file
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - sp-az-webapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'sp-az-webapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{  }}
          package: '*.jar'
      - name: Restart Azure Web App
        id: restart-webapp
        uses: azure/Restart-AzWebAppSlot@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'sp-az-webapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{  }}
          package: '*.jar'


You are referring to the Restart-AzWebAppSlot PowerShell cmdlet used in Azure. Since this cmdlet is meant for Azure PowerShell, it can be useful if you're running scripts directly in a CI/CD pipeline with PowerShell enabled, such as in Azure DevOps pipelines or any other environment that supports PowerShell.

If you use GitHub Actions for CI/CD, integrating this specific PowerShell cmdlet directly into a GitHub Action will not work as smoothly because the cmdlet is part of Azure PowerShell and requires an Azure login context.


I tried adding Restart-AzWebAppSlot in the deployment steps in .yaml file but didn't work.


Azure has no built-in support in GitHub action which named as Restart-AzWebAppSlot, that's the reason why it wouldn't function as expected.
There is no official GitHub action by that name.
GitHub actions for Azure require specific commands or Azure CLI steps to handle tasks like restarting.

Use Azure CLI (az webapp restart) to perform the restart. The Azure CLI command can be incorporated into the pipeline after the deployment step.
.yaml file:
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - sp-az-webapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'sp-az-webapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: '*.jar'

      # Restart the Azure Web App after deployment
      - name: Restart Azure Web App
        run: |
          az webapp restart --name sp-az-webapp --resource-group <your-resource-group> --slot Production

I used the Azure CLI to restart the web app using the az webapp restart command.
Build status:
Starting job: Build
Checking out repository...
> actions/checkout@v4
✓ Checked out repository code

Setting up Java version...
> actions/setup-java@v1
✓ Set Java version to 17

Building project with Maven...
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:my-app >------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/runner/work/my-app/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Copying resources to /home/runner/work/my-app/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /home/runner/work/my-app/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Copying resources to /home/runner/work/my-app/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Tests are passing
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default-jar) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/runner/work/my-app/target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Installing /home/runner/work/my-app/target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to local repository

[INFO] Build success

Job deployment:
Starting job: Deploy
Downloading artifact from build job...
> actions/download-artifact@v3
Artifact 'java-app' downloaded successfully.

Deploying to Azure Web App...
> azure/webapps-deploy@v2
[INFO] Using publish profile from secret.
[INFO] Deploying jar file: /home/runner/work/my-app/target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to app 'sp-az-webapp'
✓ Deployment successful.
Web App URL: https://sp-az-webapp.azurewebsites.net

Azure Login:
Logging into Azure...
> azure/login@v1
Using Service Principal credentials from secret: 'AZURE_CREDENTIALS'
✓ Azure login successful.


